# Python - Obtain a list of parenthetical tuples from string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a string such as:
`(1,2,3,'4.1),(4.2)',5,6,7),(8,9,10)`. The output I need to obtain is the list: 
`[ ((1,2,3,'4.1),(4.2)',5,6,7), (8,9,10) ]`
I believe I need a regex in order to perform this task. How can I do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Regex can help you doing that. Does the pattern you mentioned (`(1,2,3,'4.1),(4.2)',5,6,7),(8,9,10)`) can change (numbers, structure, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, it can change. In reality it is a long string. I need to parse out each of the strings inside the outermost parentheses.

Comment: @PhilDulac Actually, (arbitrarily deeply) nested parenthetical expressions are a canonical context-free example that regular expressions cannot capture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to evaluate the string directly (after putting it in a list).

```
from ast import literal_eval

string = "(1,2,3,'4.1),(4.2)',5,6,7),(8,9,10)"

literal_eval('[{}]'.format(string))
# [(1, 2, 3, '4.1),(4.2)', 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10)]
```

Comment: `literal_eval` isn't evil, because it doesn't run any code